# Open source native library for file copy/move in andorid

Tags: android, native

Is there any easy to use, open source or free android **native** library for copying and moving files/directories in android?

UPDATE : for better performance I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at[apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)

example: (where inputStream is a file inputStream)

```
OutputStream o=new FileOutputStream("path");
int bytes=IOUtils.copy(inputStream, o);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

BEST!

```
private static void copyFileUsingFileChannels(File source, File dest)
        throws IOException {
    FileChannel inputChannel = null;
    FileChannel outputChannel = null;
    try {
        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
        outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
        outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
    } finally {
        inputChannel.close();
        outputChannel.close();
    }
}
```

MORE:https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/